# How can I archive email offline in an indexable format?

Tags: mail.app, email, archive, indexing

When my emails reach a certain "age" I do want to keep them, but I do not want them cluttering up my Mail.app and taking up space on my server.

My current strategy is to:

1. filter them by sender, then
2. move all the filtered items to a working folder, then
3. Export that folder to my storage device (it saves in mbox format), then
4. Delete the contents of the IMAP/working folder

This does work to save space and cleans up my email client; however, it also:

1. Is a cumbersome process, and
2. Creates the non-indexable mbox format

**Is there any way (method, or software) that will archive my emails on offline media in an indexable and searchable format?** I would prefer to be able to search by subject, date, sender, sent/received, and content.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmm… pretty quiet here. I'm thinking applescript-ing might be the way to go. If anyone has any thoughts on this, please let the forum know. It might take me a while to develop something, but I will post it here when I do.